# How to make a ghost element in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Imagine, There is two elements, A **`<select></select>`** tag and I add an **arrow-down icon** on this select. The problem is that I don't want to simulate a click on the select if the user click on the arrow cause it's too lame...

So I would know if it's possible to make an element visible but allow the user to click on the element behind. As if the element is a ghost, you can pass through it with your cursor.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `pointer-events: none`

Comment: Thank you Jonathan you're the first.
My question sounds like dumb.. right know. That is the kind of attribute we never heard about.

Comment: @Jonathan You should make your comment an answer so it can be accepted instead of someone else getting rewarded for the answer you came up with. Also see the compatibility table for `pointer-events`: http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the visible element, you can set the pointer events to none.

```
#downarrow{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

After that, just place the clickable thing right under it.

Comment: It should be noted that `pointer-events` [isn't supported by IE10-](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)